# java heap memory dump from the aws EC2 instance with tomcat8

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, heap-dump

I have a Ubuntu 16.4 on an AWS EC2 instance and I have installed java 1.8 and tomcat 8 on this machine. I have deployed one Spring MVC application on this  machine. Quite often it gets out of memory issue. I want to analyze the heap dump and I tried by using the below command.

sudo jmap -dump:format=b,file=/opt/tmp/heapdump.bin 37320

But when I execute the above command got the below message.

Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded

I want to get the java heap dump from my EC2 instance. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file might help to resolve.

Comment: This dint not solve my problem , i need to get the java heap dump from EC2 instance , are there any other way i can get the dump. My tomcat8 memory is increasing gradually even though if there is no load on the server.

Comment: I even tried the options specified in the below link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959122/memory-fully-utilized-by-java-concurrenthashmap-under-tomcat