# Javolution FastSortedMap in Threaded Environment

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, treemap, concurrenthashmap

I'm trying to find an alternative to using java.utils.TreeMap in a threaded environment due to the memory TreeMap consumes and doesn't free, using Sun JDK 1.6. We have a constant resizing TreeMap, which needs to keep sorted by key:

```
public class WKey implements Comparable<Object> {

    private Long ms = null;
    private Long id = null;

    public WKey(Long ms, Long id) {
        this.ms = ms;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((ms == null) ? 0 : ms.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        WKey other = (WKey) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (ms == null) {
            if (other.ms != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!ms.equals(other.ms))
            return false;
        return true;
    }        

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        WKey k = (WKey) arg0;

        if (this.ms < k.ms)
            return -1;
        else if (this.ms.equals(k.ms)) {
            if (this.id < k.id)
                return -1;
            else if (this.id.equals(k.id)) {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        return 1;
    }

}

Thread 1
-------------------------
Iterator<WKey> it = result.keySet().iterator();

if (it.hasNext()) {
    WKey key = it.next();

    /// Some processing here

    result.remove(key);
}

Constantly retrieves the first element within the TreeMap and then 
removes it.

Threads 2, 3, and 4
-------------------------

    for (Object r : rs) {
        Object[] row = (Object[]) r;
        Long ms = ((Calendar) row[1]).getTimeInMillis();
        Long id = (Long) row[0];
        WKey key = new WKey(ms, id);

        result.put(key, row);
     }

Are bulk processing threads which process returned results from various 
services, which are generally basic POJOs. POJOs are generated a key 
based off their id and timestamp using the key above. I cannot 
modify the POJO to implement a Comparator, so I must use this key.
After keys have been identified and process, they are inserted into a 
shared tree map where they are getting pulled off in sorted order by
a processing thread.

We were using:

Map<WKey, Object[]> result = 
   Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<WKey, Object[]>());

We also tried using ConcurrentSkipListMap:

SortedMap<WKey, Object[]> result =
     new ConcurrentSkipListMap<WKey, Object[]>();
```

We are experimenting with big data and need a collection which sufficiently utilizes memory any time remove or put is used in a threaded environment. We are inserting records by the hundred-thousands and removing elements from the top on a needed basis. We need a container which can scale. The problem with TreeMap is it never releases memory unless you recreate the container, new Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap()) . This is an expensive operation to call in a threaded environment anytime a new entry is removed.

Alternatively, I've been experimenting with [Javolution](http://javolution.org/apidocs/index.html). It has a FastSortedMap, which seems to fit in nicely. However, I find their implementation and usage of the collection rather quirky and lacking sufficient [documentation and examples](http://javolution.org/apidocs/index.html).

They do have a few examples listed in the doc, which relate to the clases FastSortedMap is derived from, but nothing seems to work:

```
A high-performance hash map with real-time behavior. Related to FastCollection, fast map supports various views.

atomic() - Thread-safe view for which all reads are mutex-free and map updates (e.g. putAll) are atomic.
shared() - View allowing concurrent modifications.
parallel() - A view allowing parallel processing including updates.
sequential() - View disallowing parallel processing.
unmodifiable() - View which does not allow any modifications.
entrySet() - FastSet view over the map entries allowing entries to be added/removed.
keySet() - FastSet view over the map keys allowing keys to be added (map entry with null value).
values() - FastCollection view over the map values (add not supported).
```

I instantiated the following collection as a replacement to TreeMap:

```
private FastMap<WKey, Object[]> result =
    new FastSortedMap<WKey, Object[]>().shared();
```

However, once another thread touches the container. All the member functions start to fail. I still encounter null values returned from result.iterator().next(), size() sometimes hangs, result.keySet().min() is very sluggish. result.get returns null. None of the examples in doc really show how the concurrent views are used, listed above. It's really frustrating.

I've looked a at [Apache Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/userguide.html#Ordered_Maps), but I'm afraid I might experience the same issue as many of their sorting collections are derived from java.utils HashMaps and TreeMaps.  I looked into [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) as well, but their sorted containers require you to implement comparable on both key and value. I was trying to avoid implementing comparable on the 'value'. I don't need to sort both objects. If I implemented comparable on the value, I would just use a sorted list, queue, or table. [Highscale](http://sourceforge.net/projects/high-scale-lib/) and [Trove](https://bitbucket.org/robeden/trove/overview) don't have ordered maps. [Fastutils](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) may be a candidate, but I'd have to synchronize everything manually, and I'm trying to save time.

I've reviewed others listed in the [stackoverflow benchmark post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629804/what-is-the-most-efficient-java-collections-library), but the projects listed previously seem to be my best alternatives.

So far, I'm not convinced [Javolution](http://javolution.org/apidocs/index.html) is everything they advertise on their site. My experience is that their implementation is very inconsistent, lacking documentation, and performs rather sluggish in threaded environments. TreeMap performs great; I just wish it wouldn't allocate in such large bursts and GC every now and then. However, I'm hoping there might be somebody out there to prove me wrong, may even demonstrate appropriate usage for Javolutions collections in a threaded environment.

Otherwise, if somebody knows a way around resizing Treemaps, without using 'new', or has solved similar/alternative instances working with threading and sorted maps, any info would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean, "never releases memory"?  GC is the only way memory gets released, and TreeMap does delete references to removed entries.

Comment: During runtime, TreeMap consumes most of my memory space. Using clear() or remove() doesn't seem to free references as described here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811537/is-java-hashmap-clear-and-remove-memory-effective. The recommendation here, mentions recreating the TreeMap, however, that is an expensive operation, and I'm trying to find alternatives.

Comment: Eh?  That refers to `HashMap`, and in any event, the Java _language_ has no concept of freeing references; you only dereference an object and the GC picks up after you.  Alternately, you might want `ConcurrentSkipListMap` for a properly concurrent sorted map implementation.

Comment: You're correct, should be 's/free references/dereference/'. I tried ConcurrentSkipListMap and experienced the same issue as described in the HashMap post mentioned above. I admit, I was insinuating the issue was related as they all derive from AbstractMap. Regardless, I've further isolated my issue in a unit test. clear() and remove() work fine for both TreeMap and ConcurrentSkipListMap. It seems my issue may reside elsewhere. I'll have to dig some more. Will see...