# Freeing a HashMap and considering shrinkage

Tags: java, android

I want to properly free the memory associated with a `HashMap`. This answer suggests using `clear()`

[Map.clear() vs new Map : Which one will be better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757868/map-clear-vs-new-map-which-one-will-be-better)

Though, it does not take into account that `clear()` does not shrink the capacity to the original size. So, clearing a `HashMap` of 10k items, will leave behind the space of those 10k items.

On the other hand, this answer suggests using `null` and it takes into account the shrinkage and suggests that you use `null` instead of `clear()`

[how to clear objects (HashMap) to be garbage collected - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407307/how-to-clear-objects-hashmap-to-be-garbage-collected-java)

I am using the `HashMap` to cache items on start and process them after some other processing. When I am done with them, I do not need them anymore. Though, if the user decides to perform the same operation (rarely happens), I use the `HashMap` again to cache the items and process them, then get rid of them.

I am bit confused. Which approach should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: '... clearing a `HashMap` of 10k items, will leave behind the space of those 10k items': no it won't. It will leave behind the space for 10,000 *references*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407307/how-to-clear-objects-hashmap-to-be-garbage-collected-java) (which you went through),

**Setting the Map to null** will do the work. But remember that **garbage collection happens in the background, and only when it is required. So you may not immediately see a lot of memory being freed**.

You can even take a look at **WeakHashMap** [here](https://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/09/difference-between-weakhashmap-and-hashmap-with-exmaple.html). It's keys are 'Weakreference'-d hence garbage collected eagerly.

WeakHashMap is ideal for a scenario like this: (Quoting from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-weakhashmap))

*Let's say that we want to build a cache that keeps big image objects as values, and image names as keys. We want to pick a proper map implementation for solving that problem.*

*Using a simple HashMap will not be a good choice because the value objects may occupy a lot of memory. What's more, they'll never be reclaimed from the cache by a GC process, even when they are not in use in our application anymore.*

*Ideally, we want a Map implementation that allows GC to automatically delete unused objects.*

Comment: Thanks for the information. I do not really understand how WeakHashMap works. I cache the values during the operation. Then, around a minute later, I iterate over the HashMap items. I decided to go with the `null` approach using HashMap.

Comment: A name typically is something that can be reconstructed, like a string. Using weak references therefore is a very bad idea, as when a name becomes unreachable, the value might get removed from the `WeakHashMap` while there are lookups with an equal key later on. For a cache, you either use an ordinary map or soft references (there’s no built-in map type with soft keys).

Answer (score 1):

For your usecase i think using [WeakHashMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/WeakHashMap) is best. This is very suitable for you because you don't need the hashmap for long time. so weak reference is better than a strong referenced HashMap.

```
WeakHashMap<String, String> map = new WeakHashMap<>();
    map.put("Hello", "test");
```

Comment: calling System.gc() is considered as bad practice unless you are at a terrible state of memory usage.

Comment: its just an example for testing how this WeakHashMap works. without calling the gc here, how you will know when the gc will collect your reference?

Comment: Even if you do call `System.gc()` you don't know that the GC will collect your reference.  Seriously, just don't do it.  You will give someone the wrong idea that *they* should do it.

Comment: The string `"Hello"` will never be garbage collected, so it’s pointless to use a `WeakHashMap` with such a key.