# Hashmap - iterating and getting the ouput printed too many times

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

In the below code contains_All hashmap is putting the key and value for each iteration.
After for loop I am clicking on next button   again putting the name and state in hashmap
so my hashmap should contain all the values for every page.
But when i am printing the hashmap
I am getting 4 lists

1. The key and value of 1 page.
2. The key value of 2 pages along with 1 page
   3.The key value of 3 page along with 1 and 2
3. The key value of 4 pages along with previous all

NOw when I am iterating the map I am getting too many values as it is printing 1, 2,3 and4
But I want only the 4 which contains all

```
public static validate()

{ 
get value();
    while (utils.isElementDisplayed(next)) {

            utils.waitForElement(next, 20);
            utils.click(next);
            getValue();

        }

public getValue{
for (int i = 0; i < allRows.size(); i++) {

            names = ds_name.get(i).getText();
            seName = ds_server.get(i).getText();
            state = ds_state.get(i).getText();
            String names_seName = name_ds.concat("_" + serverName_ds);

            containsAll.put(names_seName, state);

        }

        System.out.println(containsAll);
        Iterator it = containsAll.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry ent = (Map.Entry) it.next();

            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(ent.getKey() + "= " + ent.getValue());
            Reporter.log("-----------------------------------------------------------");
            Reporter.log(ent.getKey() + "=  " + ent.getValue());

        }
}
```

Comment: Well first thing that comes to mind is that you keep filling the `containsAll` hashmap without ever removing thing out of it. So first fill it with page 1, then add page 2, and so on. Of course it will keep all the previous values. Solution: clean out the hashmap or make a new one per page.

Comment: @Fullslack.dev how can i remove the things and get only the last one which contains all the values.
I dont want to make new Hahmaps for all pages

Comment: If you only use the hashmap inside the `for loop`, I would move the declaration inside there as well. On _clearing_ or _removing values_ in hashmap I would take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811537/is-java-hashmap-clear-and-remove-memory-effective

Comment: @Fullslack.dev  I cleared the hashmap but now i get the value of 4 page only
But i want the value of all pages together

Comment: Oké, I hope I understand the question now (the formulation is terrible with double 3. and a reference to 4. that doesn't exist). So you want to see this printed right `The key value of 4 pages along with previous all`. In order to do that, return to your original code (forget my previous comments) and move the `Iterator it = containsAll.entrySet().iterator();` and subsequent code block out of the `for loop`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Fullslack.dev yes it worked. Thankyou so much :-)

Comment: Glad it did. Could you accept the answer I provided please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display `The key value of 4 pages along with previous all` you need to move the *displaying* code block outside the *for loop*. In this case it is the block of code starting with `Iterator it = containsAll.entrySet().iterator();`.

Complete code sample:

```java
public static validate() { 
    get value();
    while (utils.isElementDisplayed(next)) {
        utils.waitForElement(next, 20);
        utils.click(next);
        getValue();
    }

public getValue {
    for (int i = 0; i < allRows.size(); i++) {

        names = ds_name.get(i).getText();
        seName = ds_server.get(i).getText();
        state = ds_state.get(i).getText();
        String names_seName = name_ds.concat("_" + serverName_ds);

        containsAll.put(names_seName, state);
        System.out.println(containsAll);
    }
    
    Iterator it = containsAll.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry ent = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(ent.getKey() + "= " + ent.getValue());
        Reporter.log("-----------------------------------------------------------");
        Reporter.log(ent.getKey() + "=  " + ent.getValue());
    }
}
```

The reason this works and the original code doesn't is because you fill the hashmap and print it as well. In doing so you print *page 1*, then *page 1 & 2*, then *page 1,2 & 3* and finally *page 1,2,3 & 4*. Moving the print outside the *for loop* only prints the finished hashmap.