# HashMap.clear() reduce memory?

Tags: java, memory, hashmap

```java
System.gc();
System.out.println((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/1024/1024);// print 1M

Map map=new HashMap();
for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
    map.put("key"+i,"i");
}
System.gc();
System.out.println((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/1024/1024); //print 10M

map.clear();
System.gc();
System.out.println((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()));//print less than 1M
```

It seems the memory is reduced when call the clear method. However, from looking at other answers it seems the `clear` method never shrinks the `HashMap`. So why is the memory reduced?

Comment: *"But base on the other answers..."* Would you add the links to the answers where you thought you read that?

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/2811633

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2811612

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're referring to [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811537/is-java-hashmap-clear-and-remove-memory-effective), they're telling you that the entries array (`table`) in the `HashMap` is never shrunk. Instead, its entries are all set to `null`.

But clearing the map makes the 100,000 strings you created (`"key0"`, `"key1"`, ...) and their associated `Map.Entry` objects eligible for garbage collection, despite `table` not getting smaller.

Comment: And indeed, if we assume that the `HashMap` grows naturally, most of the map's memory usage will be the hash entries, and the keys and values they link to.   Which `clear()` is discarding.

Comment: thank you for your answer. From the answer,  clear will release the memory, but  retain the table size.

Comment: if  i don't call the System.gc() method ,how long will the memory could be garbaged?

Comment: @Ran - How long is a piece of string? :-) It depends on the JVM's garbage collection implementation and (probably) the other demands on memory in the app.

Answer (score 5):

It's an implementation detail, so the exact answer may change depending on the exact version of Java.

Here's the Java 8 implementation of `HashMap::clear`:

```
public void clear() {
    Node<K,V>[] tab;
    modCount++;
    if ((tab = table) != null && size > 0) {
        size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; ++i)
            tab[i] = null;
    }
}
```

The table of buckets is completely emptied, but the table itself, and so the non-default capacity, is retained.

Regardless of the exact implementation, you would expect to free up a significant chunk of memory, because all of those non-interned strings created by `"key"+i` will be eligible for collection.

If you really care about reducing the capacity back to default then just reassign the HashMap with a new instance.